# Re-open or merge request

Tags: support, status-completed, reopen-request

I'd like to request that [this](https://superuser.com/questions/491008/how-do-i-shutdown-windows-8) question is reviewed. I don't feel that the question marked as such is in fact an exact duplicate, as this question was created to discover the rather hidden official way (it took me a week to stumble over it back in the preview days) of actually shutting down a Windows 8 system, and the votes seem to indicate some consensus on the problem. I feel it is a great help to new users on its own.

Alternatively, a merged question covering all the potential ways of shutting down the system could be a better question, and would be happy to re-work the question as it is to cover this.

Comment: I voted to reopen the question, but to be honest, the word "proper" bothers me.

Comment: Thank you, I know what you mean as I'm not either really, I'll try harder to find a  more graceful alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question has been reopened by the community.

<sup><sup>(fun fact: 3 of the 5 who initially voted to close have also voted to reopen it)</sup></sup>